# GET http://localhost:8100/ net::ERR_CACHE_READ_FAILURE

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, ionic-framework

I get the following Chrome error about 20 times:

> GET http:://localhost:8100/video/ping.mp3 net::ERR_CACHE_READ_FAILURE

I try to replace a div, if the barcode scan is correct. I'm embedding the HTML5 audio tag in my replacement. When to user clicks the button which will be active if the barcode is correct the div container-* should be replaced and this works, but the audio doesn't play and i get the error above.

What's my mistake?

Any help much appreciated

I have this code:

```
var mp = document.getElementById("mp3");
function play() {
mp.play();
}
    function scan() {
      cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
        function(result) {
          if (result.text == "home") {
            var atHomeRepQR = '<div class="container-h"><div class="card"><div class="item item-text-wrap "><i class="icon ion-unlocked"></i> Diese Ansicht ist entsperrt.</div></div><button onclick="play()" class="button button-positive btn">Play</button></div><audio id="mp3"><source src="video/ping.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>';
            save("atHomeSaveQR", atHomeRepQR);
          }
          if (result.text == "street") {
            var atStreetRepQR = '<div class="container-s"><div class="card"><div class="item item-text-wrap "><i class="icon ion-unlocked"></i> Diese Ansicht ist entsperrt.</div></div><button onclick="play()" class="button button-positive btn">Play</button></div><audio id="mp3"><source src="video/ping.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>';
            save("atStreetSaveQR", atStreetRepQR);
          }
          if (result.text == "bern") {
            var atBernRepQR = '<div class="container-b"><div class="card"><div class="item item-text-wrap "><i class="icon ion-unlocked"></i> Diese Ansicht ist entsperrt.</div></div><button onclick="play()" class="button button-positive btn">Play</button></div><audio id="mp3"><source src="video/ping.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>';
            save("atBernSaveQR", atBernRepQR);
          }
          if (result.text == "bahnhof") {
            var atBahnhofRepQR = '<div class="container-ba"><div class="card"><div class="item item-text-wrap "><i class="icon ion-unlocked"></i> Diese Ansicht ist entsperrt.</div></div><button onclick="play()" class="button button-positive btn">Play</button></div><audio id="mp3"><source src="video/ping.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>';
            save("atBahnhofSaveQR", atBahnhofRepQR);
          }
          if (result.text == "atelier") {
            var atAtelierRepQR = '<div class="container-at"><div class="card"><div class="item item-text-wrap "><i class="icon ion-unlocked"></i> Diese Ansicht ist entsperrt.</div></div><button onclick="play()" class="button button-positive btn">Play</button></div><audio id="mp3"><source src="video/ping.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>';
            save("atAtelierSaveQR", atAtelierRepQR);
          }

        },
        function(error) {
          alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
        }
      );
    }
```

Comment: try pressing Ctrl+F5 keys at the same time. It must clear cache

Comment: @ManasovDaniel thanks, that helped, but the function play() doesn't get called... Do you know why? This is correct syntax right? `<button onclick="play()" class="button button-positive btn">Play</button>`